# Swift2 reflection help. Convert the value I get (type Any?) to Bool or Bool? accordingly

Tags: reflection, swift2

for a unit test of mine, I wrote a small helper that can get me a property Value by name.

```
let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
let child1 = m.descendant(name)
```

now the problem is that the child has Type Any? but the properties real type is e.g. Bool? So Any is actually an Optional!

Thats why `if child1 is Bool?` never fires because Any? isn't the Bool?.
But `child1! is Bool?` doesn't compile.
And `child1! is Bool` isn't true!

So how do I 'unbox' this reflected Any? value?

---

a small example of what I mean

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let name = "asd"
    let boolvalue: Bool = true
    var optboolvalue: Bool? = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print( getNumberForBool("boolvalue") )
        print( getNumberForBool("optboolvalue") )
    }

    func getNumberForBool( name: String ) -> NSNumber {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        let child1 = m.descendant(name)

        if(child1 != nil) {
            //! only works for bool, not for bool?
            if let b = child1  as? Bool {
                return NSNumber(bool: b)
            }
            //this would be my interpretation of how to do it ... unwrap the any and unwrap it again. this doesn't compile though :)
//            if let b = child1! as! Bool? {
//                return NSNumber(bool: b!)
//            }
        }

        return NSNumber(bool: false)
    }
}
```

NOTE

The type of child1 for the case Bool?:

▿ Optional(Optional(true))
  ▿ Some : Optional(true)
    - Some : true

Comment: have you tried `let child1 = m.descendant(name) ?? false` ?

Comment: I added a small example of my issue in the question. problem is that unwrapping the descendant may leave me with another optional which i'd have to unwrap too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### solution

I worked around the issue of not being able to cast an to Bool? by using reflection again

```
        if let any = child1, let maybeB = Mirror(reflecting: any).descendant("Some") as? Bool {
            if let b = (maybeB as Bool?) {
                return NSNumber(bool: b)
            }
        }
```

reflection ^ 2 :D

#### the complete gist:

https://gist.github.com/Daij-Djan/18e8ab9bcbaa3f073523

Answer (score -1):

the `??` operator unwraps the optional in case there is `Some` inside. If there is not, the value that is passed after eg. `let foo = someOptional ?? alternativeValue`.

This would give you an unwrapped `Any`. Since Swift is strongly typed you will only be getting the Bool if you would cast.

```
if let b = child, let c = b as? Bool {
       return NSNumber(bool: c)
}
```

Comment: But any is a bool? It isn't that any? Is the bool?

Comment: I added an example of my issue in the question