# swift reflection and the any type

Tags: swift, reflection

I'm trying to use swift reflection to manage changes to properties of various classes. In testing with a playground, I put together the following code:

```
class myClass
{
    var fieldOne:String?
    var fieldTwo:Int?
    var fieldThree:Float?
}

var oneMyClass = myClass()
oneMyClass.fieldOne = "blah"

let aMirror = Mirror(reflecting: oneMyClass)

for thing in aMirror.children
{
    print(thing.label!)
    print(thing.value)
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
fieldOne
Optional("blah")
fieldTwo
nil
fieldThree
nil
```

The property names are great but I don't want the Optional, I just want the value so, of course, I unbox it by using:

```
print(thing.value!)
```

Except that returns the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/blahblahblah...swift:21:22: error: 
cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>')
print(thing.value!)
      ~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

when it hits the nil values.

BUT, if you try to compare thing.value to nil, it tells you that an Any type cannot BE nil so you're not allowed to make that comparison.

Any ideas on what I can do, however convoluted, to get either just the value itself or the nil?

You can see the dilemma of an Any having a nil value if you add:

```
if thing.value == nil
{

}
```

After the print(thing.value) statement. The error states that an Any cannot BE nil so you can't do the comparison but the previously run code clearly shows thing.value IS nil.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift2 reflection help. Convert the value I get (type Any?) to Bool or Bool? accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707460/swift2-reflection-help-convert-the-value-i-get-type-any-to-bool-or-bool-acc)

Comment: You could use https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection to get a clean dictionary of all property values. When using EVObject as the base object you could also compare 2 objects which would do a field level evaluation. you can also try testing for mirror.displayStyle == .Optional and then get the mirror.children.first.value

Answer (score 0):

If all your trying to do is observe changes to values of a class, look no further than [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/).

```
class SomeClass {

    let myBool:MutableProperty<Bool> = MutableProperty(true)

}
```

You have to wrap each property you want to observe in a `MutableProperty` struct (or a `ConstantProperty`, `AnyProperty`, etc depending on what you want) and then you can use the `producer` property of that wrapper to observe whenever a value changes.

```
let object = SomeClass()
object.myBool.producer.on(next: { value in 
    print(value)
})
```

You use the `on` method to inject side effects to the observation of that property. There's a lot of events, `interrupted`, `completed`, `next`, just to name a few.

Also reflection in Swift is fairly slow. To give you an idea, take a look at [this article](http://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/). Creating 2000 `NSManagedObject` instances natively is 3.5 times the speed of it's reflection counterpart.

Comment: Unfortunately, the changes I'm looking for aren't real time. It's a delayed process to send modified values to a server as a block. This might work but it would seem more complicated than I was hoping for.

Comment: I understand, something like that is absolutely possible using RC. And its probably better than reflection b/c you'll 100% know the type of the variable.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is "RC"?